# rtkit-daemon[1119]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action

Tags: linux, kernel, oracle-12c

I am using Oracle Linux Server release 7.9, we have installed oracle 12c on this machine and running a consistent load. During the night time after running the test for more than 8-10 hours, suddenly system becomes unavailable, we can not access it through ssh,

Although we have analyzed from zabbix monitoring, there could not be anything significant which can lead to this problem. Almost system CPU, ram and everything was running in good state but after this time Feb  1 03:00:45 no further system stats were reported in zabbix monitoring. Also in system messages, we noticed netdata process was also killed

```
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 40121 (netdata) score 1091 or sacrifice child
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: Killed process 40367 (go.d.plugin) total-vm:734908kB, anon-rss:7536kB, file-rss:0kB
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: sadc invoked oom-killer: gfp_mask=0x2000d0, order=0, oom_score_adj=0
```

the following is/var/log/messages of that time.

```
Feb  1 03:00:45 dbserver12c rtkit-daemon[1119]: The canary thread is apparently starving. Taking action.
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c journal: Missed 7209 kernel messages
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18900] 54321 18900 15544518  1030233    6865        0             0 oracle_18900_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18902] 54321 18902 15544520  1747806   11245        0             0 oracle_18902_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18904] 54321 18904 15544540  1440254   10264        0             0 oracle_18904_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18906] 54321 18906 15544518  1440851   11007        0             0 oracle_18906_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18908] 54321 18908 15544260     9409    1556        0             0 oracle_18908_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18910] 54321 18910 15544519   995625    7062        0             0 oracle_18910_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18912] 54321 18912 15544519  2130982   11237        0             0 oracle_18912_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18914] 54321 18914 15544518  1521359   10979        0             0 oracle_18914_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18916] 54321 18916 15544519  1352952    8390        0             0 oracle_18916_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18918] 54321 18918 15544258     8682    1496        0             0 oracle_18918_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18920] 54321 18920 15544520  2030372   11048        0             0 oracle_18920_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18922] 54321 18922 15544519  1149189    8514        0             0 oracle_18922_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18924] 54321 18924 15544518   919024    7466        0             0 oracle_18924_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18926] 54321 18926 15544519   792075    8359        0             0 oracle_18926_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18928] 54321 18928 15544257     7481    1256        0             0 oracle_18928_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18930] 54321 18930 15544520  1933402   11155        0             0 oracle_18930_or
Feb  1 03:00:46 dbserver12c kernel: [18932] 54321 18932 15544519   842684    8489        0             0 oracle_18932_or
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Since you have Netdata monitoring on the server, have you checked what it was reporting right before the crash? If I recall correctly, it also tracks per-process resource usage, so look at which process was using the most RAM?

Comment: Specifically I would like to ask what is this rtkit-daemon[1119]: The canary thread 
What has made my system unavailable?